# Can we have number value on the top of charts bars.?

Tags: chart.js

[image]

User needs to know the value directly instead of mouse hovering on it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/). The [positioning](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/positioning.html#anchoring) of the labels is specified by the following definition inside the chart options.

```
plugins: {
  datalabels: {        
    anchor: 'end',
    align: 'end',
  }
}
```

Please have a look at the runnable code snippet below.

```js
const labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'];
const data = labels.map(l => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
const sortedData = data.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b);
const backgroundColors = data.map(v => sortedData.indexOf(v) >= data.length - 3 ? 'red' : 'green');

Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My Dataset",
      data: data,
      backgroundColor: backgroundColors
    }]
  },
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        top: 30
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'end'
      }
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.3.2/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```