# Show values in Bar chart javascript

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bar-chart

I would really appreciate if you could help me with this problem.
I need to be able to show the values at the top of the bars that were drawn, that is to say that they are not only seen when the mouse passes over the bar, but show the static values.
This is the final chart:
[image]

And, this is my code:

```
        success: function(response){
                $("#myChart2").remove();
                $("#Grafica2").append('<canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>');
                var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                var labels = [];
                var colors = [];
                var values = [];
                for(var i in obj){
                    colors.push(getRandomColor())
                    labels.push(obj[i].TipoConsult)
                    values.push(obj[i].PzsTotal)
                }
                new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart2"), {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                    labels: labels,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                        label: "Total piezas scrap generadas",
                        backgroundColor: colors,
                        data: values
                        }
                    ]
                    },
                    options: {
                    legend: { display: false },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Total de piezas scrap generadas por "'+TipoConsulta+'" entre las fechas '+FechaMin+' y '+FechaMax
                    }
                    }
                });
        }
```

Comment: I would highly recommend pasting your code into the post rather than taking an image of it to make it easier for those who answer to be able to replicate pieces and highlight segments.

Comment: what you are asking should be hidden inside the documentation of the chart.js. If chart.js does not provide such ability, you may do it from scratch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we have number value on the top of charts bars.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62320721/can-we-have-number-value-on-the-top-of-charts-bars)