# Output labels over the bar - Possible with ChartJS 4.3.2?

Tags: chart.js, label

In the previous version it was possible to output the labels over the bar with animation.

Examle

```
animation: {
            duration: 1,
            onComplete: function ()
            {
                var chartInstance = this.chart,
                ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
                ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i)
                {
                    var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);

                    meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index)
                    {
                        var data = dataset.data[index];
                        ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
                    });
                });
            }
        }
```

But now with the newest version this code is not working anymore.
I didn't find any help on the chartjs homepage.
I hope somebody can help me?

[Example of Bar Chart with output of the labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu3yt.png)

Comment: What you need is chartjs-plugin-datalabels (see https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/)

Comment: This is working perfectly. But I get the output of the label only into the bar, but not on the top of bar.

const myChartcnvSaison = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [" 01","02"],
        datasets:
        [
   {
                label: 'pro',
                data: [10,36],
            },
        ],
        datalabels:
        {
            align: 'end',
            anchor: 'end'
        }
    },
Where is my issue?

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62371334/2358409